# Vi: Search for lines containing string1 as well as string2

Tags: vi

I know how to search for a single expression. How do I combine two?

```
/string1 & string2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use `.*string1\&.*string2`

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_patterns has many tips, at least for vim.